# How to know if the oauth access token is expired

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

**Description**

In Web Api project template, after sending a `POST` request to the *Token* endpoint: `www.mycoolwebsite.com/Token`, we get a Json similar to this:

```
{
   "access_token":"qkRwQD0A85...",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "expires_in":14,
   "userName":"admin@mycoolwebsite.com",
   ".issued":"Wed, 24 Feb 2016 18:15:53 GMT",
   ".expires":"Wed, 24 Feb 2016 18:16:08 GMT"
}
```

On the client side, (let say a mobile application) I am saving this json on a file, and to see if the token is expired, I compare `DateTime.UtcNow` to token's `.expires` key.

**Question**

Is this the correct way to see if an access token has expired?

If not, what is the best way check this?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't check the access token's expiry time. Rather than build a mechanism to check the expiration time and handle it, why not just send the access token you have to the API and, if you get a 401 back, request a new access token. You'll have to build in logic to handle 401's anyway...why not rely on that instead?

Comment: I agree with @sdoxsee The access_token should be opaque to the client.  The string is usually opaque to the client. (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.4)

Comment: @sdoxsee Server also returns 401 for other unauthorized resource access, even when the token is valid. Plus, my mobile application stores this token in a variable, as long as this variable is not `null`, the application thinks the user is Signed In, even tho the token has expired. So I want to know what is the best mechanism to sign in/out a user from a mobile client? Thanks

Comment: @AliSharabiani The spec says that 401s are for invalid tokens while 403s are for insufficient scope (i.e. privileges) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1. Handling authentication (sign in/out) is a separate matter. OAuth2 is not intented for authentication directly. OpenID Connect adds an authentication layer on top of OAuth2. I'm not sure whether or not you're in the position to change your authorization server but here's an intro to a .NET OpenID Connect one: https://vimeo.com/113604459